# Text does not fit foot line space

Tags: fontsize, fancyhdr, geometry, article

For my next essay, I got some requriements from my teacher. The layout concerning headlines and footlines should be like this (as there is no adequate Times New Roman I chose Arial):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\linespread{1.25}   
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                                                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove standard line
\fancyfoot[C]{}                    %remove some standard stuff
\fancyfoot[R]{ 
        %page \thepage\addspace of \pageref{LastPage} \\
        %This line seems to work in the original document.
        topic \\
        my name \\
        version: \date{today}
}

\begin{document}
Dies ist ein Test.
\end{document}
```

The text is printed in the right corner below, but it does not fit completely below the footnotes. In a "pdflatex"- run you will see that the "version" line goes beyond the defined 2cm.

Another part is the font size of the "\fancyfoot[R]" part, which has to be 9 pt. I know that the parameter \footnotesize already contains this size.

Which settings do I have to change?

Comment: welcome to tex.sx. Your question is quite hard to understand, you comment on using Arial but there are no font settings in your supplied code, It is always helpful if you make the examples complete (small) documents so that we can run them. If I run your code I get `! Undefined control sequence.
\f@ncyorf -> page \thepage \addspace ` are you using an additional package that defines this?, please make your example show the problem described.

Comment: To get 9pt text change the `11pt` option you are using to `10pt` (or just remove as 10pt is the default) then use `\small`. The other parts of the question need a working example I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements seem contradictory: it's quite difficult to have a bottom margin of 2cm where all that information should find its place.

However, here's the idea:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,
 left=2.5cm,
 right=2.5cm,
 top=2.5cm,
 bottom=2cm,
 footskip=45pt, % this is needed to make room for the footer
]{geometry}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove standard line
\fancyfoot[C]{}                    %remove some standard stuff
\fancyfoot[R]{\footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}
  topic \\
  my name \\
  version: \today\\[3pt]
  page \thepage\space of \pageref{LastPage} \\
  \end{tabular}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Notice `\footnotesize` for setting the font size in the footer. With a `tabular` you have more control over the various elements. There is no `\addspace` command in the LaTeX kernel; in order to get today's date use `\today`. The `lipsum` package is just for generating text, the `lastpage` package is required.

[image]

Comment: The "footskip" value in the geometry-package is a good start, some adjustments and measurement with a rule will do that (e.g. if you use 45pt you don't see anything of the foot line). Also thank you for the tabular approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} %remove standard line
\fancyfoot[C]{}                    %remove some standard stuff
\fancyfoot[R]{ \footnotesize
        page \thepage\\ %\addspace of \pageref{LastPage} \\
        topic \\
        my name \\
        version: \date{today}
}



\begin{document}


Bla, bla.

\end{document}
```